# Time Complexity of T(xn) + T((1 − x)n) + cn

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

What is the time complexity of the recurrence relation 
T(xn) + T((1 − x)n) + cn

Comment: What is the range of $x$? $0<x<1$ I suppose?

Answer (score 2):

The [Akra-Bazzi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) shows that the solution is $\Theta(n\log n)$. Details left to you.